# Thread Access Permission

Tags: c, multithreading, linux-kernel, kernel, pthreads

I am trying to test the access permissions for virtual memory space for threads created from a common process.
In order to test this, I created a system call that takes a process ID as an input, finds virtual memory space and provides the READ, WRITE, EXECUTE, SHARE and MAY_SHARE permissions for the given address space.

Following is the system call code

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/mm_types.h>
#include <linux/mm.h>
#include <asm/page.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/path.h>

asmlinkage void sys_varstats(int PID)
{
    struct task_struct *task;
    struct pid *pid_struct;

    struct mm_struct *mm;
    struct vm_area_struct *vma;

     //size of virtual memory area
    unsigned long size_area;
    //size of virtual address space
    unsigned long size_space = 0;

    pid_struct=find_get_pid(PID);
    task=pid_task(pid_struct,PIDTYPE_PID);

    printk("\nProcess ID = %d \n", task->pid);
    mm = task->mm;

    vma = mm ->mmap;
    printk("Starting_Address   Size      Permission\n");

    do {
        size_area = (vma->vm_end - vma->vm_start);
        printk("%-19lu%-10lu", vma->vm_start, size_area);

        if ((vma->vm_flags) & VM_READ)
            printk("r");
        else
            printk("-");

        if ((vma->vm_flags) & VM_WRITE)
            printk("w");
        else
            printk("-");

        if ((vma->vm_flags) & VM_EXEC)
            printk("x");
        else
            printk("-");

        if ((vma->vm_flags) & VM_SHARED)
            printk("s");
        else
            printk("-");

        if ((vma->vm_flags) & VM_MAYSHARE)
            printk("m");
        else
            printk("-");


        printk("\n");
        size_space += size_area;
        vma = vma->vm_next;

    }
    while(vma != NULL);
    printk("Total Space = %lu \n", size_space);

}
```

Now, I create five different threads which share a global array to which they perform some operation. Each thread also calls the above system call to obtain the access permissions.
Following is the code used to create multiple threads.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <linux/unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define __NR_varstats 337
#define NTHREADS 5

int global_arr[1000000];
const int s=1000000;
 void *num(void *threadid)
 {
        int n=s/NTHREADS;
    int tid = (int)threadid;
    printf("Beginning Thread %ld\n",tid);
        for(int i=tid*n;i<(tid+1)*n;i++)
        {
                global_arr[i]=tid;
                if (i==(tid*n)+(n/2))
                {
                        pid_t systid=syscall(SYS_gettid);
                        printf("PID %d %ld\n",systid,tid);
                        syscall(__NR_varstats, systid);
                }
        }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
 }

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t threads[NTHREADS];
    void *status;

    for(int t=0; t<NTHREADS; t++)
    {
       int return_code = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, num, (void *)t);
       if (return_code){
          printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", return_code);
          exit(-1);
       }
    }
    for(int t=0; t<NTHREADS; t++)
    {
        printf("Joining Thread %d\n",t);
        pthread_join(threads[t], &status);
    }
        printf("Parent Process PID %d\n",getpid());
        return 0;
}
```

The output I get from this experiment is as below. 
What I am unable to understand is that the threads below share many virtual memory spaces but still the access permission for that memory space is not shared. I was under the impression that since the threads are writing to a global list atleast one of the memory segments would be shared amongst processes.
Also, the total address space of the first thread is different, but the rest of the threads share the same amount of memory though all threads are eventually working on the same amount of data.

```
Process ID = 9402 
Starting_Address   Size      Permission
4911104            122880    r-x--
5033984            4096      r----
5038080            4096      rw---
5066752            1642496   r-x--
6709248            8192      r----
6717440            4096      rw---
6721536            12288     rw---
6770688            94208     r-x--
6864896            4096      r----
6868992            4096      rw---
6873088            8192      rw---
134512640          4096      r-x--
134516736          4096      rw---
134520832          3997696   rw---
153894912          135168    rw---
3037425664         4096      -----
3037429760         8388608   rw---
3045818368         4096      -----
3045822464         8388608   rw---
3054211072         4096      -----
3054215168         8388608   rw---
3062603776         4096      -----
3062607872         8388608   rw---
3070996480         4096      -----
3071000576         8392704   rw---
3079450624         8192      rw---
3079458816         4096      r-x--
3220262912         86016     rw---
Total Space = 48115712 

Process ID = 9403 
Starting_Address   Size      Permission
4911104            122880    r-x--
5033984            4096      r----
5038080            4096      rw---
5066752            1642496   r-x--
6709248            8192      r----
6717440            4096      rw---
6721536            12288     rw---
6770688            94208     r-x--
6864896            4096      r----
6868992            4096      rw---
6873088            8192      rw---
134512640          4096      r-x--
134516736          4096      rw---
134520832          3997696   rw---
153894912          135168    rw---
1275813888         118784    r-x--
1275932672         4096      rw---
3035627520         135168    rw---
3035762688         913408    -----
3037425664         4096      -----
3037429760         8388608   rw---
3045818368         4096      -----
3045822464         8388608   rw---
3054211072         4096      -----
3054215168         8388608   rw---
3062603776         4096      -----
3062607872         8388608   rw---
3070996480         4096      -----
3071000576         8392704   rw---
3079450624         8192      rw---
3079458816         4096      r-x--
3220262912         86016     rw---
Total Space = 49287168 

Process ID = 9401 
Starting_Address   Size      Permission
4911104            122880    r-x--
5033984            4096      r----
5038080            4096      rw---
5066752            1642496   r-x--
6709248            8192      r----
6717440            4096      rw---
6721536            12288     rw---
6770688            94208     r-x--
6864896            4096      r----
6868992            4096      rw---
6873088            8192      rw---
134512640          4096      r-x--
134516736          4096      rw---
134520832          3997696   rw---
153894912          135168    rw---
1275813888         118784    r-x--
1275932672         4096      rw---
3035627520         135168    rw---
3035762688         913408    -----
3037425664         4096      -----
3037429760         8388608   rw---
3045818368         4096      -----
3045822464         8388608   rw---
3054211072         4096      -----
3054215168         8388608   rw---
3062603776         4096      -----
3062607872         8388608   rw---
3070996480         4096      -----
3071000576         8392704   rw---
3079450624         8192      rw---
3079458816         4096      r-x--
3220262912         86016     rw---
Total Space = 49287168 

Process ID = 9400 
Starting_Address   Size      Permission
4911104            122880    r-x--
5033984            4096      r----
5038080            4096      rw---
5066752            1642496   r-x--
6709248            8192      r----
6717440            4096      rw---
6721536            12288     rw---
6770688            94208     r-x--
6864896            4096      r----
6868992            4096      rw---
6873088            8192      rw---
134512640          4096      r-x--
134516736          4096      rw---
134520832          3997696   rw---
153894912          135168    rw---
1275813888         118784    r-x--
1275932672         4096      rw---
3035627520         135168    rw---
3035762688         913408    -----
3037425664         4096      -----
3037429760         8388608   rw---
3045818368         4096      -----
3045822464         8388608   rw---
3054211072         4096      -----
3054215168         8388608   rw---
3062603776         4096      -----
3062607872         8388608   rw---
3070996480         4096      -----
3071000576         8392704   rw---
3079450624         8192      rw---
3079458816         4096      r-x--
3220262912         86016     rw---
Total Space = 49287168 

Process ID = 9399 
Starting_Address   Size      Permission
4911104            122880    r-x--
5033984            4096      r----
5038080            4096      rw---
5066752            1642496   r-x--
6709248            8192      r----
6717440            4096      rw---
6721536            12288     rw---
6770688            94208     r-x--
6864896            4096      r----
6868992            4096      rw---
6873088            8192      rw---
134512640          4096      r-x--
134516736          4096      rw---
134520832          3997696   rw---
153894912          135168    rw---
1275813888         118784    r-x--
1275932672         4096      rw---
3035627520         135168    rw---
3035762688         913408    -----
3037425664         4096      -----
3037429760         8388608   rw---
3045818368         4096      -----
3045822464         8388608   rw---
3054211072         4096      -----
3054215168         8388608   rw---
3062603776         4096      -----
3062607872         8388608   rw---
3070996480         4096      -----
3071000576         8392704   rw---
3079450624         8192      rw---
3079458816         4096      r-x--
3220262912         86016     rw---
Total Space = 49287168
```

I am unable to understand this, any explanation would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Your code printing process permission about read, write and executable etc.

when a process is created, it is represented by "struct task_struct" and memory address space of newly created process is represented by "struct vm_area_struct *vma"; vm_area_struct is maintained the starting and ending addresses of each segment in your application. Along with about permission flags.

whenever you create threads, a thread is treated as a process in side a kernel. All threads will have its own pid, so each thread will have its own vm_area_struct. That's way you see vm_area_struct is calling for each threads.

kernel differentiate threads and process by tgid, all threads that are spawned by a single process, will have same tgid but difference pid.

```
task_struct contains a pointer to struct mm_struct.
struct mm_struct contains a pointer to vm_area_struct.
```

so you need to initialize

```
mm = task->mm;
vma = mm->vma
```

Hope you understand.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you see the assorted difference? If you check kernel code, you will see threads share mm. So if you iterate over all threads, you always access the same mm in the first place.

Also the kernel code is wrong. It lacks proper locking and error checks to be viable. For instance, no steps are taken to make sure the task does not go away, mm is there and is not going away etc.

If the code was destined to only be used for introspection, you can use 'current' instead.